# Why does DEX like Uniswap requires 'approve' when 'transfer' emits the 'transfer' event?

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, decentralized-exchange

Can't the DEX watch the 'transfer' events on the blockchain and do swaps etc accordingly? Why do they require 'approve'?

Comment: DEXs are smart contracts which run on the blockchain. and they have no access to events

Comment: The person downvoting without answers is just dum as f